# Maven project showing as pomUpdated instead of jar

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I am using Eclipse with m2e.  I have one *ProjectA* that is built as a Maven project and is packaged as a Jar.  When I add *ProjectA* as a dependency in *ProjectB*, it is showing up as packaging .pomUpdated instead of Jar.  I am using the feature 'Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects'.

Any ideas?  I've tried forcing updates/snapshots and a bunch of other things, but nothing has fixed the problem. I've had this work successfully before with other projects referencing *ProjectA*, but this time it's not working.

EDIT:

The issue turns out to be that ProjectA not building, but I can't figure out why.  Apparently it is having trouble finding its parent project on my Nexus server, but I have it setup to find the parent using a relative path, which should mean it will find it locally, right?  Why would it be looking at Nexus instead?

```
Failure to find com.foobar:MyProject:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in
http://myserver/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local 
repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has 
elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

EDIT 2:

I fixed the issue with ProjectA not building, but now I'm back to only seeing pomUpdated available for ProjectB to use... very frustrating!

Comment: Have you added the dependency in your pom.xml and updated dependencies in Eclipse ?

Comment: Yes, I added the dependency to the pom.xml and updated dependencies.  That's one of the first things that I tried.

Comment: Have you done an mvn install with the project you would like to use as dependency ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with my Sonatype Nexus setup being incorrect.